# Как правильно указать имя MSSQL сервера?

Tags: powershell, sql-server

Я хочу сделать deploy ssas базы данных на сервер. Для этого использую powershell и вот [этот](http://rainydaycode.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/deploying-an-ssas-database-via-powershell/) вариант скрипта.

и в powershell пишу следующее:

```
 D:\deploy.ps1 //ИМЯ сервера в сети//MSSQL2012 D:\1.xmla
```

где:

- deploy.ps1 - скрипт из приведенного выше блога,
- 1.xmla - сгенерированный deployment wizard скрипт.

Так же пробовал писать имя копьютера либо его ИП, эффект один и тот же. На эту команду powershell отвечает:

> Исключение при вызове "Connect" с "1"
> аргументами: "A connection cannot be
> made. Ensure that the server is
> running."

Comment: Хотел ответить, но  не могу :).

Вопрос нашел свой ответ:
D:\deploy.ps1 (имя либо ИП сервера)\MSSQL2012 D:\Скрипт_деплоя.xmla

Вот такая строчка будет работать как надо. Проблема была в расстановках и направлении слешей. 

Обратите внимание, что если у вас на сервере запущен только один Instance MSSQL, то вам не нужно писать "\MSSQL2012".